# Echo Array inside an array using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to access, this array

> (certification inside release_dates inside results)

```
  "results": [
   {
     "iso_3166_1": "IN",
     "release_dates": [
     {
        "certification": "U",
        "note": "",
     }
     ]
   }
   ]
```

I am using this code:

```
 if (isset($response4["results"]) && is_array($response4["results"])) 
 {
     foreach ($response4["results"] as $genreObject) 
     {
         $release_dates_iso_3166_1 = $genreObject["iso_3166_1"];
         $release_dates_certification = $genreObject["release_dates"]["certification"];
         $stmt->execute();
      } 
  }
```

But this code only access `iso_3166_!` not `certification`

> Error: Notice: Undefined index: certification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `release_dates` is array and you must be use first element of this array:

```
if (isset($response4["results"]) && is_array($response4["results"])) 
{
    foreach ($response4["results"] as $genreObject) 
    {
        $release_dates_iso_3166_1 = $genreObject["iso_3166_1"];
        $release_dates_certification = $genreObject["release_dates"][0]["certification"];

        $stmt->execute();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`release_dates` key contain arrays, not object. So you should iterate or access the keys.

```
if (isset($response4["results"]) && is_array($response4["results"])) {
    foreach ($response4["results"] as $genreObject) {
       $release_dates_iso_3166_1 = $genreObject["iso_3166_1"];
       $release_dates_certification = null;
       foreach ($genreObject["release_dates"] as $release_dates_elements) {
           $release_dates_certification = $release_dates_elements["certification"];
       }
    }
}
```